# How to plot using multiple criteria in R?

Tags: r, plot

Following are first 15 rows of my data:

```
> head(df,15)
   frame.group class lane veh.count mean.speed
1     [22,319]     2    5         9   23.40345
2     [22,319]     2    4         9   24.10870
3     [22,319]     2    1        11   14.70857
4     [22,319]     2    3         8   20.88783
5     [22,319]     2    2         6   16.75327
6    (319,616]     2    5        15   22.21671
7    (319,616]     2    2        16   23.55468
8    (319,616]     2    3        12   22.84703
9    (319,616]     2    4        14   17.55428
10   (319,616]     2    1        13   16.45327
11   (319,616]     1    1         1   42.80160
12   (319,616]     1    2         1   42.34750
13   (616,913]     2    5        18   30.86468
14   (319,616]     3    3         2   26.78177
15   (616,913]     2    4        14   32.34548
```

'frame.group' contains time intervals, 'class' is the vehicle class i.e. 1=motorcycles, 2=cars, 3=trucks and 'lane' contains lane numbers. I want to create 3 scatter plots with frame.group as x-axis and mean.speed as y-axis, 1 for each class. In a scatterplot for one vehicle class e.g. cars, I want 5 plots i.e. one for each lane. I tried following:

```
cars <- subset(df, class==2)
by(cars, lane, FUN = plot(frame.group, mean.speed))
```

There are two problems:

1) R does not plot as expected i.e. 5 plots for 5 different lanes.
2) Only one is plotted and that too is box-plot probably because I used intervals instead of numbers as x-axis.

How can I fix the above issues? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time a new plot command is issued, R replaces the existing plot with the new plot. You can create a grid of plots by doing `par(mfrow=c(1,5))`, which will be 1 row with 5 plots (other numbers will have other numbers of rows and columns). If you want a scatterplot instead of a boxplot you can use `plot.default`

It is easier to do all this with the ggplot2 library instead of the base graphics, and the resulting plot will look much nicer:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(cars,aes(x=frame.group,y=mean.speed))+geom_point()+facet_wrap(~lane)
```

See the ggplot2 documentation for more details: http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/

Comment: Thank you. I was avoiding ggplot2 up until now. But now is the time to learn it. You gave me motivation for it, thanks.